# Get all JTextField by order

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtextfield, gettext

I use Netbeans to create GUI with a number of `JTextField` elements. I want iterate through all of them to call `setText`, the text will be just 1, 2, 3 ...

```
private javax.swing.JTextField txt1;
private javax.swing.JTextField txt2;
private javax.swing.JTextField txt3;
private javax.swing.JTextField txt4;
private javax.swing.JTextField txt5;
private javax.swing.JTextField txt6;
```

I'm looking for a way to do this in a loop instead of calling `setText` by hand for each of them.

May be something like that:

```
public void getInfoJText2(){
    Component[] children = jPanel1.getComponents();
    for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i] instanceof JTextField) {
            ((JTextField) children[i]).setText(Integer.toString(j++));
        }
    }
}
```

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 6):

Use an array (or List) of JTextFields and iterate through that instead. If you don't want to get rid of the drag-and-drop GUI (which is a poor way of creating a GUI, since you'll have to rely on the GUI builder totally), you can still put the textfields in an array.

When the textfields have been initialized, create an array that's accessible in your `getInfoJText2()` method, then put the references to the textfields in the array, i.e.

```
JTextField[] fields = new JTextField[6];  // Instance variable in the class

public void initArray() {
    fields[0] = txt1;
    fields[1] = txt2;
    fields[2] = txt3;
    // etc.
}
```

Then you can use your fields -array in the getInfoJText2() method and the order will always be the same.

Comment: But I use Netbean and create all jtextfield by drop and drag. I don't know handle with jtextfield manual. So I used to create array JTextField[]. Then I put JTextField[0] = txt1, and so on. It can be. But I wonder if have someway I make it faster

Comment: You can still put them in an array. However, if setting the text is the only thing you are doing with the array, it won't be worth the effort.

Comment: *"But I use Netbean and.."*  ..I am it's obedient servant?  It's time you started to use the IDE rather than the other way around.

Comment: Thank you. Now I know what you mean

Comment: @mKorbel Indeed, I didn't have time to write out a proposed solution here :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getInfoJText2() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field[] fields = jPanel1.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field field : fields) {
        if(field.getName().contains("txt") && field.getType().getName().equals(JTextField.class.getName())) {
            JTextField jField = (JTextField)field.get(jPanel1);
            jField.setText(field.getName().substring(3));
            System.out.println(jField.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

you can try the above core. it uses reflection

Comment: Reflection is a very bad replacement for something which can be achieved with a simple loop over a list / array.